# The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth' 2

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to learn how to get a flutter app to login to firebase auth. I've created a new flutter project using the android studio plugin and added the dependencies. I'm getting the error "The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'" when trying to call the method. Can someone please tell me the solution, i am a beginner in flutter and would appreciate any help.

```
    //THIS IS LOGIN.DART
    
    class Login extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
    }
    
    class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      SharedPreferences preferences;
      bool loading;
      bool isLogedin = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        isSignedIn();
      }
    
      void isSignedIn() async {
        setState(() {
          loading = true;
        });
        preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        isLogedin = await googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
        if (isLogedin) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        }
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      }
    
      Future handleSignIn() async {
        preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
        setState(() {
          loading = true;
        });
        GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleUser.authentication;
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithGoogle(
            idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
            accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
          final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
              .getDocuments();
          final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
          if (documents.length == 0) {
            //insert the user to our collection
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(firebaseUser.uid)
                .setData({
              'id': firebaseUser.uid,
              'username':firebaseUser.displayName,
              'profilePicture':firebaseUser.photoUrl
            });
            await preferences.setString('id', firebaseUser.uid);
            await preferences.setString('username', firebaseUser.displayName);
            await preferences.setString('photoUrl', firebaseUser.photoUrl);
          }else{
            await preferences.setString('id', documents[0]['id']);
            await preferences.setString('username', documents[0]['username']);
            await preferences.setString('photoUrl', documents[0]['photoUrl']);
          }
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Login was successful');
          setState(() {
            loading = false;
          });
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
    
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    
        } else {
    
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login failed");
    
        }
      }
    
    //THIS IS PUBSPEC.YAML dependencies
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
      firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
      cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
      google_sign_in: ^5.0.1
      shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
      fluttertoast: ^8.0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

All signing in to Firebase Authentication with OAuth tokens from social providers is now done through `signInWithCredential`.

For a code sample of this, see the FlutterFire documentation on [signing in with Google](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social#google).

Answer (score 0):

You have to go in the android file of your project in cmd command and type

```
./gradlew signinReport
```

this should fix it